# Why my code is skipping last row from the excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

Can someone please help on this code, it is always skipping the last row
below is my code, from this code I'm trying to remove the bold font

```
import openpyxl
import re
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
sample_rows = [i for i in range(1, len(data))]
for r in sample_rows:
  cell = sheet_obj.cell(row=r, column=1)
  if cell.font.b == True:
     cell.value = None
  if cell.font.b == True and cell.font.i == True:
     cell.value = None
  if re.search('bold', cell.font.name.lower()):
     cell.value = None
  data.iloc[r][col_number] = cell.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does that `data` come from? Anyhow, let's assume it is an object (a pandas dataframe?) whose length is equal to the number of rows, e.g. 10: you are then looping on a range from 1 to 9, so you always miss the last row.

Btw the code has a few other issues:

- testing for `cell.font.b` and `cell.font.i` after you already tested for `cell.font.b` alone is useless: the second test will never be `True` it the first one is `False`
- why use `re` to just check for a substring in a string? `'bold' in cell.font.name.lower()` is surely faster
- the assignment in the last line is probably not working as expected: it will be executed only if the last test succeeds, but not if the first one does

Comment: Data is my dataframe when i loop it from 0 i'm getting `ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1` error
Can you please suggest me that how i can get that last row actually those are if condition by mistake i made it as elif

Comment: `range(1, len(data)+1)` If `len(data)` evaluates to N you are looping from a `start` of 1 to a `stop` of N, i.e. from 1 to (N-1). So you need to add 1. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

Comment: yes i tried this as well getting `index out of range` error

Comment: Wait: your rows in Excel are 1 to 10, but in the dataframe they are 0 to 9. So if `r` is now going from 1 to 10 the final assignment needs to use `r-1`. Or you may use `range(len(data))`, i. e. 0 to 9, and use `r+1` when retrieving the cell